# How to ignore invalid characters in android's manifest

Tags: android, eclipse, manifest

I have the common manifest file of android, and let's say i have this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

if i add a special character in the permission like '@'

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS@" />
```

Eclipse gives me the error "Tag  attribute name has invalid character '@'."
Obviously because of the '@'.

So, i want to compile my program with any special character i want in the manifest.
I tried disabling error checking by going to `Window->Prefences->Android->Lint Error Checking`

it didn't work.
I also tried disabling XML validator by going to `Window->Prefences->Validation`

It didn't work either. (or maybe i have do something wrong in the last step, eclipse was saying something about full rebuild, maybe i didn't applied the settings properly?)

Comment: But why would you even need it? If it's a permission, it wouldn't have any special character.

Comment: I'm curious - why do you need that? Even if you manage to accomplish that, Android will probably consider this permission to be different from `RECEIVE_SMS`, so your app will break.

Comment: I'm a security reasearcher, it's really important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in Eclipse:

1. Open "Problems" view. It is usually located in a bottom part of the eclipse window (where logcat is)
2. There will be "Errors" there: "Tag <uses-permissions> attribute has invalid character...".
3. Right click this error message and delete it.

Now you should be able to export signed application or deploy it onto the device.

You'll have to do  this each time this error reappears.

Comment: @maria - yeah, I was also pleasantly suprised by how Eclipse allows to override it's behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that 
It is specified in the android SDK. You can never change these "constant" strings. Android identifies what permissions you want to use for your application.

Although, For res/strings.xml, as they are strings to be used in your application, you can use allowed special characters.

Comment: Isn't there any workaround for this? I think that you can change Manifest's permissions by "force" if you decompile an APK, edit it(insert the character i mentioned) and recompile it with apktool. Or it won't let you recompile?

Comment: @maria -- If you want custom permissions that's whole another story !!

Comment: @maria - actually I think there is a way - I was able to reproduce it in my eclipse. See my answer.

Comment: As of now I did not know it was possible. Lemme try it too.. !